# WP tabs for flexslider wont play the next 2nd and 3rd slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I am using flexslider and WP visual composer tabs for the gallery.. but it only the 1st/default tabs that plays the flexslider the 2nd and 3rd tabs won't play the flexslider...

this is the content and shortcode:

```
[vc_tabs interval="0" el_class="gallery-tabs"][vc_tab title="Models" tab_id="1394091656-1-78"][vc_column_text]

[gallery ids="11686,11685,11684,11683,11682,11681,11680,11679,11678,11677,11676,11675,11674,11673,11672,11671,11670,11669,11668"]

[/vc_column_text][/vc_tab][vc_tab title="Community" tab_id="1394117053869-1-9"][vc_column_text]

[gallery ids="11703,11702,11701,11700,11699,11695,11696,11697,11698"]

[/vc_column_text][/vc_tab][vc_tab title="Events" tab_id="1394117071776-2-2"][vc_column_text]

[gallery ids="11758,11757,11756,11755,11754,11753,11752,11751,11750,11749,11748,11747,11746,11745,11744,11743,11742,11741,11740,11739,11738,11762,11763,11764,11765,11766,11767,11768,11770,11771,11772,11773,11774,11775,11776,11777,11778,11779,11780,11781,11782,11784,11785,11786,11787,11788,11789,11790,11791,11792"]

[/vc_column_text][/vc_tab]
```

and this is the script...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(".flexslider").flexslider({animation: "slide",directionNav: false,controlNav: "thumbnails"}); 
            jQuery(".flex-control-nav").jcarousel({vertical: true,scroll:1});
            $(".swipebox").swipebox();
            jQuery('.gallery-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li').click(function() {
                $(".flexslider").flexslider({animation: "slide",directionNav: false,controlNav: "thumbnails"}); 
                jQuery(".flex-control-nav").jcarousel({vertical: true,scroll:1});
                $(".swipebox").swipebox();
                console.log("ok");
            });
        });
```

but when I try to put an `alert()` in the click function the slides will show up but it is annoying the alert.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(".flexslider").flexslider({animation: "slide",directionNav: false,controlNav: "thumbnails"}); 
            jQuery(".flex-control-nav").jcarousel({vertical: true,scroll:1});
            $(".swipebox").swipebox();
            jQuery('.gallery-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li').click(function() {
                $(".flexslider").flexslider({animation: "slide",directionNav: false,controlNav: "thumbnails"}); 
                jQuery(".flex-control-nav").jcarousel({vertical: true,scroll:1});
                $(".swipebox").swipebox();
                alert("test");
            });
        });
```

Does anyone had an idea about this? thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Flexsliders and other plugins inside DOM elements that are hidden on load won't be initialized, often because it can't properly calculate dimensions. You'll need to use your tabs plugin's callback mechanism to initialize each Flexslider when its tab is selected.